# Expression must have a pointer type error

Tags: c++

I have read the other similar posts, but still haven't found a way to solve my coding problem.

Here is the code:

```
   void Foo(vector<Name> &obj){

           vector<Name> *temp = 0;

           temp = new vector<Name>;
           if (!temp){
                std::cout << "temp Allocation Error!" << std::endl;
                exit(1);
           }


           temp->push_back(obj[n]);  

           std::cout << temp[0]->member_function() << std::endl;
   }
```

Foo is a universal function.

I have a function Foo that takes a reference to a vector container. Within Foo there is a dynamic vector called temp.

I use push_back() to insert an obj into the temporary vector.

Then I wish to access that obj stored in the temporary vector in order to access its member function.

However this is where the compiler says that "expression must have pointer type".

Could somebody please explain how to rewrite this line of code.

```
     std::cout << temp[0]->member_function() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Can you tell us *why* you want to use a pointer?

Comment: Holy memory leak. What's the dynamic allocation for?

Comment: Oh, and for your problem (which could be totally avoided if not using pointers) [a good `std::vector` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) could help.

Comment: Where have you initialised the value of n?

Comment: I didn't include the code where I then go on to delete the dynamic vector, since that isn't the problem here.

Comment: `new` throws `std::bad_alloc`. Your attempt to handle a failed allocation doesn't work. Even if you would have `nothrow`, it would not have been necessary to assign `0` to the pointer first.

Answer (score 2):

```
temp[0]->member_function()
```

This treats `temp` as if it were an array of pointers-to-vector, which it's not.

You need to dereference `temp` *before* performing array subscripting on the result:

```
(*temp)[0].member_function()
```

Honestly, though, dynamic allocation here is pointless and is giving you a memory leak right now.

Answer (score 0):

You have a vector of Name objects, and not Name*, but you use the "->" operator instead of "." which is what the compiler is telling you.

You should either try:

```
std::cout << (*temp)[0].member_function() << std::endl;
```

or make the vector elements Name*.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp[0]->member_function()
```

would be correct if `temp` were a vector of pointers, but it isn't – it's a pointer to one vector.
And you can't use `->` with a vector.
(It is equivalent to `(*temp)->member_function()`.)

You can say

```
(*temp)[0].member_function()
```

but the better solution is usually to avoid dynamic allocation completely:

```
vector<Name> temp;
temp.push_back(obj[n]);  
std::cout << temp[0].member_function() << std::endl;
```